# play store vs hockey app crash reporting

Tags: android, google-play, hockeyapp

Hockey app allows me to automatically pull crash reports; without the user explicitly sending the report each time. Does the play store do the same thing for my app? With hockey app, I have to use a function ( `CrashManagerListener`). How would I accomplish the same with the play store?

Comment: This is absolutely besides the question, but I am usually pissed whenever my phone sends stuff via network if I do not request it, and error reports are certainly something that I usually don't want my apps to send (at least when I'm not on wifi).

Comment: The Play Store does not automatically send an error report, although after an app crashes there is an option to send an error report. I would leave it up to the user... You'll get plenty of voluntary reports, believe me.

Answer (score 0):

No, Playstore/Appstore does not do that.

Though, I would like to add that don't use the "send reports automatically" via HockeyApp. I might seem convenient, but trust me, many users won't appreciate it that your app is doing things in the background without their consent. 
I would have given my user an option to send or not to send the error reports back to me.